# Custom navbar in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, navbar

I want to have a custom navbar as follows:

- Centered logo
- 3 menu buttons to on the left (collapsible)
- 2 icons (account and instagram) on the right (always-expanded)

When collapsed, I expect to see hamburger icon on the left, logo in the center, two horizontally aligned icons on the right. I checked [navbar examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/navbars/) and saw nothing similar to what I am looking for.

Here is my attempt. It seems to be working except that when left menu gets collapsed, right menu becomes vertical rather than staying horizontal.

```css
.navbar-brand.abs {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="Navbar example">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand abs" href="#">Logo</a>
    
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Shop</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">X</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Y</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning is rarely needed and tends to cause more problems than it solves. There's also rarely a need to write custom CSS for layout with Bootstrap.

It seems the solution here is simply to reorder the document to match your description. If you prefer other document order you can probably make use of Bootstrap's [flex order classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/#order). I also took the logo and second menu out of the collapse structure, and I changed the nav type of the second menu to get it horizontal.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark px-3" aria-label="Navbar example">
  <div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pt-2 ms-2" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Shop</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>

  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">X</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Y</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```